# Visual Studio 2008 Blank Tool Window

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008-sp1

I have a blank property window that I can not get rid of in Visual Studio 2008 SP1. I have tried every thing to get rid of it.

If I close it it shows right back up after going into debug mode or restarting visual studio. I have tried every thing to fix all the way to reinstalling VS with no luck.

Does any one have a solution for this?

[image: Blank Property Window]

Comment: Tried to click on the pin then toolbox? Or ALT+SHIFT+ENTER.

Comment: Did you uninstall a VS addin?

Comment: @SLaks It did first show up when I uninstalled a addin

Answer (score 3):

**Use the following fix:**

Close all instances of Visual Studio Navigate to the following directory (I am using 2008 – for a different version change the 9.0 to reflect the correct version number/folder)

```
"%userprofile%\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0".
```

You should see four files:

1. `toolbox.tbd`
2. `toolbox_reset.tbd`
3. `toolboxIndex.tbd`
4. `toolboxIndex_reset.tbd`

Move these files to another folder (or, if you are very brave, delete them altogether. Note, this is very much a case of “Worked on my (colleague’s) PC” – do this at your own risk. Restart Visual Studio and hey presto, your Toolbox should be back to where it needs to be. The user in question did not have any custom items in his toolbox so I can only assume that the fix reverted the toolbox to the original Visual Studio state.

Answer (score 0):

Click Window, Reset Window Layouts.

If that doesn't help, click Tools, Import and Export Settings, Reset all settings.  (But backup your current settings)

Comment: That had no affect on it. It did not even go away for a sec.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to try is via the Visual Studio 2008 command line you can run the following command.

```
devenv /resetsettings
```

This will restore to factory settings, this could clear up the issue, re-install wouldn't do this for you.